# Script to remove characters from a file name for all files in a folder

Tags: regex, bash

So basically, I want to write a script that would be able to remove characters from a file name until it hits a letter. Ex. if I were to run it in a folder containing files:

```
13. abc
0 2 d ef
1.ghi3
```

It would rename the files to

```
abc
d ef
ghi3
```

Thanks

Comment: I assume those leading spaces are significant and not a typo? Also, spaces aren't considered "letters" so please specify exactly what characters you're referring to. Finally, show us what you've tried so far. We're not here to do your work for you, but to help you with specific problems!

Comment: @miken32: The spaces were an artifact stemming from _edits_ of the original post (which used backticks rather than indentation, but had no leading whitespace), so I've removed them. It's fair to assume that "letter"  means `[[:alpha:]]`, to put it in terms of  a POSIX character class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
for f in *; do
  echo mv "$f" "$(sed 's/^[^[:alpha:]]*//' <<<"$f")"
done
```

For safety, the `mv` command is prefixed with `echo`; remove the `echo` to peform actual renaming.

The above is a **POSIX-compliant** implementation.

Note that **`rename` is NOT a POSIX utility**, so you can:

- neither rely on its presence,
- nor rely on it to work the same across platforms.

An **overview of popular platforms** with respect to `rename`:

- **Debian-based platforms** such as **Ubuntu** have a ***Perl*-based** `rename` utility:

  - It expects Perl statements, most notably `s///` to perform substitutions based on regular expressions.

    - This is what [Avinash Raj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33534580/45375) relies on - a great option *if* available.
  - Dry-run support with `-n`
- **Fedora** has an **entirely different utility** that comes **from the `util-linux` package**:

  - Supports replacement of *literal* substrings only.
  - NO dry-run support.
- **macOS** has **NO `rename` utility** at all.

  - Via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) you can install a Perl-based one (`brew install rename`) whose features are a superset of what the Perl-based implementation on Debian-based platforms offers.

Answer (score 1):

You may use rename command.

```
rename 's/^[^a-z]+//' *
```

Comment: If your platform happens to have a _Perl_-based `rename` utility, this is a great solution, e.g. on Debian-based platforms such as Ubuntu. This answer won't work on Fedora (different `rename` utility) and OSX (no preinstalled `rename` utility at all).